# Regex - Prevent Double Spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large regular expression for a name field that looks like this.

```
^(?:(?!(?:.*[ ]){2})(?!(?:.*[']){2})(?!(?:.*[-]){2})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}'-]{3,48}$))$
```

I am not a Regular Expression expert, I got it this far through the help of Stackoverflow and RegexBuddy. But there is one line I am having some trouble with. The first positive lookahead, `(?!(?:.*[ ]){2})`, this prevents there from being multiple spaces.

That is not **quite** what I want. I just want to make sure that there cannot be **multiple spaces in sequence**. Like double spaces and the like. This regex prevents there from being more than 1 space in the entire string.

I've been trying to figure out how to change that, but I am really stumped. Is there any way to enforce such a concept with the rest of the regex?

C# is where this will be executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `(?!(?:.*[ ]){2})` with `(?!.*[ ]{2})`

An explanation:

`(?:.*[ ]){2}` first matches a single space preceded by zero or more other chars (`(?:.*[ ])`), which is then repeated two times (`{2}`).

`.*[ ]{2}` matches two successive spaces preceded by zero or more other chars.

Comment: Yes, this did indeed work. I do not understand why, though. Can I further annoy you for a bit of explanation?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now. So the `(?:` was telling it to constrain the number of times a specific expression could be evaluated, but placing it all within the `(?!` changed it to match the sequence throughout the string, rather than just checking for a number of spaces. Thank you very much! I will hit accept when SO's time limit lets me.

Comment: @Ciel, ah, the `(?: ... )` was confusing you. Have a look at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to see the difference between `( ... )` and `(?: ... )`. And you're welcome!